# Google Script not Finishing Successfully

Tags: google-apps-script

I recently adapted a short piece of script to automatically send an e-mail to me when a specific response appears (the word FAIL) in a 'Google docs' spreadsheet, that collects responses from volunteers using a 'Google Form' to record their weekly checks on life-saving equipment.

The email on FAIL is working well, having tested it with a few FAIL responses. However, as the form 'owner' I am receiving notifications from Google, for each normal PASS response submitted, telling me that the script failed to finish successfully.

**8/4/15 10:57 AM
SendGoogleForm
ReferenceError: "found" is not defined. (line 35, file "Code")
formSubmit**

It finishes successfully if a FAIL response is submitted, so I suspect that, due to my inexperience with scripts, I have not defined what should happen when found is 'not true'.

It's probably glaringly obvious to a more experienced script writer but none of the things I have tried with 'Else' seem to work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

function Initialize() {

```
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

for (var i in triggers)
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);

ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
    .onFormSubmit().create();
```

}

function SendGoogleForm(e) {

```
if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() < 1) return;

// Recipients email address
var email = "12345@abcde.co.uk";

// Subject for Google Form email notification
var subject = "Weekly Checks - FAIL Submitted";

var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var columns = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
var message = "A check form has been submitted containing a ** FAIL ** response:  ";
// Look for a 'FAIL' response
var key = columns[keys];
for ( var keys in columns ) {
  if ( e.namedValues[columns[keys]] == 'FAIL')  {
    found = true; 
  }
}

// Only include form fields that are not blank
if (found) 
    for (var keys in columns) {
    var key = columns[keys];
    if (e.namedValues[key] && (e.namedValues[key] !== "")) {
        message += key + ' : ' + e.namedValues[key] + "\n\n";
    }
}

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your found variable is null whenever a non-"FAIL" occurs in your script and I think your if(found) is creating the error message.

You could Initialise your variable:

var found = false;

before you start testing it. That way, your if(found) will be false and it will skip down to your send email code.

Comment: That does stop the error notification but causes an e-mail to be sent for every response. The idea of the script is to send an e-mail only when a FAIL is seen. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Then shouldn't the email code be inside your if (found)?

Comment: The email sending part of the code is executing with "every" run through but you only want it to execute when found == true. The reason why it looks like FAIL is working is because the error code is stopping the emails from being sent, not because found==true.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying to your explanation, I've been away.  I have now associated the send mail with the found ==true and added an else which seems to have done the trick. No errors in the execution transcripts for both conditions. Thanks for pointing out the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps u can use
`if ( e.namedValues["Pass or Fail"] == "Fail" ) { ... }` 
where "Pass or Fail" is the form question title. And also use `e.range.getRow()` to capture the sheet row that the responses were written.

Comment: There are several prescribed questions on the form and the responses vary, not just Pass or Fail but Not applicable, expiry dates and numeric answers. At present the script sends an e-mail when it finds the word FAIL in the latest submission, which is exactly what I need. I could just turn off error notifications but I feel that would be just hiding my sloppy work! Thanks for taking the time to reply though.